# Java Swing: getting reference to GUI component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller

I have started to learn Java and thus Swing as well. I have been looking into building a GUI and wondering, how can I get the reference of GUI component to modify/read/delete it after I created it. Do I have to hold on to the reference I get when creating the component? Or is there something like in Javascript: `document.querySelector(), .querySelectorAll(), .getElementBy...()`?

As an example we can use a button and a label. When I click the button, I want to change the label. Everyone in this example seems to just hold on to the reference they got when creating the components.

I have read about MVC and so on, but that seems to me that it is even more advanced and more suitable for bigger apps.

Could you please also point me in the right direction of learning Swing - reliable source of information - (there are tons of tutorials, but not all of them seem to be of sufficient quality).

Also I am aware that I will have to learn MVC at some point to create more sophisticated GUIs. So if you could share some reliable links on that topic I would also be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Essentially, the "easiest" solution is to maintain a reference to the components you wish to modify

Comment: *if I would be doing something bigger, where it would not be practical to store all the references,* - why would it not be practical?  Give a real example and we should be able to provide a solution. *Could you please also point me in the right direction of learning Swing* Start with the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for working example of most Swing basics. *(there are tons of tutorials, but not all of them seem to be of sufficient quality)* - post links to the tutorial you have used so we don't spend time repeating suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, an easy way of acquiring a reference to a desired component, is just to store the reference yourself. For your example where a button updates a label, you can maintain somewhere the reference to the label in your code. For example:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
    
    //Utility method to create a String with random contents:
    private static String randomString(final int length) {
        
        //Create the alphabet:
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        alphabet += alphabet.toUpperCase();
        alphabet += "0123456789";
        
        final int alphabetLength = alphabet.length();
        final Random rand = new Random();
        final char[] chars = new char[length];
        
        //Fill the random String:
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i)
            chars[i] = alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(alphabetLength));
        
        return new String(chars);
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Initialize a JLabel with a random text:
        final JLabel label = new JLabel(randomString(10));
        
        //Change font to MONOSPACED BOLD (of the current size):
        label.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, label.getFont().getSize()));
        
        //Create the JButton:
        final JButton button = new JButton("Click to change label text");
        
        //See here we maintain a reference to the label in the lambda expression:
        button.addActionListener(event -> label.setText(randomString(10)));
        
        //Create a Container (JPanel is-a Container) for the button and the label:
        final JPanel contents = new JPanel(); //FlowLayout by default.
        contents.add(button);
        contents.add(label);
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Declares that the application will exit when we click the close icon of the frame.
        frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
        frame.pack(); //Adjust the size of the frame according to its contents.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Make the frame centered in screen.
        frame.setVisible(true); //Show the frame.
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        //Always call Swing related code on the EDT. On way to achieve this is by calling invokeLater like so:
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::createAndShowGUI); //Main::createAndShowGUI is just another lambda expression.
    }
}
```

The most reliable source of information for Swing, according to my knowledge, is the official turorial of Oracle in the following link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html which leads to many more links of tutorials about many topics on Swing.

As for the helper methods to get a reference of a `Component`, `Window`, etc other than the current one, you can use the methods in [`SwingUtilities`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) class, such as:

- [`getAncestorNamed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAncestorNamed-java.lang.String-java.awt.Component-): Every `Component` has-a name with corresponding [accessor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName--) and [mutator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName-java.lang.String-) methods. As such, you can get a refernce to a `Component` by name.
- [`getRoot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getRoot-java.awt.Component-): When you are creating `Component`s and adding the to `Container`s, and essentially `Window`s, you create a `Component` tree hierarchy. You can access the root `Component` of that hiearchy for any given `Component` via a call to this method.
- [`getUnwrappedParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getUnwrappedParent-java.awt.Component-): Every `Component` belonging to a tree hierarchy of `Component`s has an ancestor (unless it is the root `Component` or a `Component` not belonging to any hierarchy yet). You can get its ancestor with this method.
- [`getWindowAncestor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor-java.awt.Component-) and [`windowForComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#windowForComponent-java.awt.Component-): With those two equivalent methods, you can get the first **`Window`** ancestor of a `Component` (which in turn already belongs to a tree hierarchy of `Component`s).

But the most common case is that you will rarely use those methods (depending on your programming style) and usually maintain a reference, to all the `Component`s you need, in your class.

Finally there are also some common methods for accessing all `Component`s of a `Container` such as [`getComponents`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents--) which returns all the `Component`s inside a `Container` (and note here `JFrame` is-a `Window` which is-a `Container`).

The reverse operation (ie getting the parent `Container` on which a `Component` belongs to) is performed with [`getParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent--) on a `Component`.

Most of those methods are used after you add your `Component`s to the tree hierarchy. For example there is not point in getting the window ancestor of a `Component` which is not added to any `Window`.

Comment: So there are not any methods to get the reference, just the ones you listed - they get a component that has a specific relationship to another componen?. So that leaves just storing the reference in a variable. And next step in this is using MVC to the full extent? I.e. if I would be doing something bigger, where it would not be practical to store all the references, I would use MVC? (I am using "MVC" as some kind of a placeholder for everything more advanced I will have to learn and MVC itself might be just a part of that.) And thanks for the link, it will come in handy.

Comment: These are just as far as I know and to get you started. You may wait if you like for more answers from professionals to come. I also updated the answer to include the most common child accessors (such as `Container#getComponents()` method) (see the last sentence). All those mentioned methods in this answer get a `Component` (or many `Component`s at a time, such as in the case of `getComponents`) which belong[s] to the same `Component` tree hierarchy as the  one you have. If you want for example to create multiple modeless windows in your app, you will have to store their reference somewhere.

Comment: [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is just the design pattern which Swing relies upon. For example the *View* are the `Component`s, the *Model* is a `TableModel` for a `JTable` for example, and so on... If you where to do something bigger, then you can do whatever suits your needs and is at the same time considered good practice. I am not an expert on best practices though, so that's a different story I guess. I just hope to shed some light on your question and not add missleading information.

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //runs when button is pressed

            button pressed = (JButton)e.getSourse();
        }
        
    });
```

you can add a actionListener to a button and then get the button instance from the Event e

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setVisible(true);
    
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
    f.add(button);
    
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("pressed");
            JButton b = (JButton)e.getSource();
            b.setSize(200,200);
        }
        
    });
```

thats how I tested it, and it just works fine